# How to find corrupted avro file in unix

Tags: hive, avro

I have few .avro files in Unix. How can I find if the files are corrupted?

I am trying to insert Avro data from `tableA` to `tableB` using insert statement using Hive. I have been getting vertex failed error. I am assuming that some particular Avro file is corrupted.

```
Error:
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523309222013_3304_3_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1523309222013_3304_3_00_000001, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row <json rows>
```

Comment: Start with providing your code and the error message.

Comment: Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523309222013_3304_3_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1523309222013_3304_3_00_000001, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row <json rows>

Comment: Please check the error above

Comment: Could please [edit] the question and include full traceback (if present).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Avro DataFileRepairTool to weed out bad avros. There is a mode for reporting errors. The tool is available in 1.8.x of avro.